# Reload Data every time I navigate to Page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have this Windows Phone Page where I load data through the standard ViewModel scope.

```
public Profile()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            App.PersonalizedViewModel.favorites.Clear();
            DataContext = App.PersonalizedViewModel;
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (!App.PersonalizedViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
            {
                App.PersonalizedViewModel.LoadData();

            }
}
```

This works fine. However when I navigate to this page from some other page the data is still the same. I mean the `LoadData()` method should recheck updated data right? Please suggest.

EDIT:

My PersonalizedViewModelClass:

```
public class PersonalizationViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PersonalizationViewModel()
    {
        this.favorites = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        this.Bar = new ObservableCollection<Bars>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> favorites { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Bars> Bar { get; private set; }

    private string _sampleProperty = "Sample Runtime Property Value";

    public string SampleProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _sampleProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _sampleProperty)
            {
                _sampleProperty = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SampleProperty");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and adds a few ItemViewModel objects into the Items collection.
    /// </summary>
    public async void LoadData()
    {
        favorites.Clear();
        try
        {
            var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Favorite")
                .WhereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username);
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();

            this.favorites.Clear();

            foreach (ParseObject result in results)
            {
                string venue = result.Get<string>("venue");
                string address = result.Get<string>("address");
                string likes = result.Get<string>("likes");
                string price = result.Get<string>("price");
                string contact = result.Get<string>("contact");
                this.favorites.Add(new ItemViewModel { LineOne=venue, LineTwo=address, LineThree=likes, Rating="", Hours="", Contact=contact, Price=price, Latitude="", Longitude="" });

            }




            if (favorites.Count == 0)
            {
                //   emailPanorama.DefaultItem = emailPanorama.Items[1];
                MessageBox.Show("You do not have any saved cafes. Long press a cafe in main menu to save it.");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data could not be fetched!", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation of PersonalizedViewModel:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        await App.PersonalizedViewModel.LoadData();

        user_tb.Text = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username;


        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("item"))
        {
            var index = NavigationContext.QueryString["item"];
            var indexParsed = int.Parse(index);
            mypivot.SelectedIndex = indexParsed;
        }

        if (NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
        {
            var length = NavigationService.BackStack.Count() - 1;
            var i = 0;
            while (i < length)
            {
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know how you implemented your ViewModel, but the `if (!App.PersonalizedViewModel.IsDataLoaded)` line seems to hint that the data will be loaded only once, no matter how many times you navigate to the page

Comment: @KooKiz removing that didn't help either!

Comment: I have also edited and added the PersonalizedViewModel Class

Comment: What do you mean by `data is still the same`? What data?

Comment: Data that is supposed to be fetched. Say in run1 it fetches a list of 2 items. But when I add another item and go back, it doesn't show the list of 3 items instead shows just precious 2 only. @JustinXL

Comment: What's the implementation of `App.PersonalizedViewModel`? Could it be because you have two different instances on two pages?

Comment: I have added the implementation in the edit. @JustinXL

Comment: I mean the `PersonalizedViewModel` property in your `App.xaml.cs` class...

Comment: Here's that: `private static PersonalizationViewModel fav = null;
        public static PersonalizationViewModel PersonalizedViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
                if (fav == null)
                    fav = new PersonalizationViewModel();

                return fav;
            }
        }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67447/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-abhishek-de).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the problem, however, I think you need to narrow in on the problem.

First off, you are calling LoadData from 2 places.  1 from MainPage_Load and 1 from OnNavigatedTo.  In MainPage_Load it is conditional and in OnNavigatedTo it is always being called.  I suggest that you get to a single path through the code instead of 2 so that you don't get different experiences.  I personally recommend (without knowing all the details) that you call load data from OnNavigatedTo instead of MainPage_Load.  If you want to do it conditionally that is fine but  if you are loading the data from memory, it really is unnecessary as you won't improve performance anymore than a few milliseconds.  Also, if you are not loading from memory, you may not want to load it conditionally because the underlying data may have changed.  In either case, the choice to load data or not should be moved out of the view and into the data layer (but that is for another post).

Once you have a single path chosen (i.e. calling LoadData from MainPage_Load or OnNavigatedTo) you should use your debugger.  Put a break point in LoadData method and if it is being called appropriately, then your problem is more specific than your posted question.  Here are some questions to think about (you may want to start from the last question and work your way backward)

Questions:

1. Is LoadData being called appropriately?
2. Does ParseObject have the correct data?
3. Is the ParseUser...UserName set properly?
4. Is the foreach being executed the proper # of times (i.e. does the result of your query have the right # of items?)

Couple Code Tips completely unrelated to this problem:

1. Single Path through code.  Don't call LoadData from more than one place.
2. Don't call favorites.clear() twice in the same method. (it is called twice in LoadData)
3. Consistent naming.  favorites is lowercase but Bar is upper case.
4. User proper data types.  On your ItemViewModel you have Hours, Latitude, and Longitude.  You have them as strings.  These clearly are not strings.  Also, you should not set them to empty.  Empty means they have been set to a value.  Emtpy is a valid value.  Null means not set.  To keep your objects clean and accurate you want to be accurate in how you set things and then deal appropriately with the impact.  If you really really want them to be initialized to empty strings, then at least do it in the constructor of ItemViewModel so that every caller doesn't have to know how to initialize every property.  I guarantee this is leading to buggy code if you continue using this practice.

Please take the comments as constructive criticism not criticism.  I know many people don't like to hear these things but the teams I lead write bugs until they start following these types of guidelines.

Good luck,

Tom

Comment: thanks a lot, will keep those in mind. Moving on, all is well except ParseObject returns outdated value although it shows updated value in its website( i mean parse.com Data Browser). Thanks again. Anyway I have left Parse and used Azure Mobile Services which is working just great!

Comment: Glad that you seem to have it working now.  Based on your comment it sounds like ParseObject doesn't have the proper data returning when LoadData is being called.  If you need assistance with this I would adjust the question a bit to focus in on this specific problem now that you are narrowed in.  Even though Azure is working, it might be good to understand why the other solution didn't work.  Good luck!

Comment: it'd be greatly helpful if you help me understand that, i mean the specific problem part.

Comment: Based on your comment I would suggest putting a break point after await query.FindAsync().  Then confirm if the data being returned is accurate or not.  If it is accurate then you have a binding issue.  If it is not accurate then I suggest forgetting about the binding and the UI and focus on the query and why isn't is returning the proper value.  I'm not familiar with ParseObject.  If that is generating a service call it could be that the service is caching and not returning the underlying value but instead the cached value.  I would need more info to assist.

Comment: Exactly service is using a cache but I can't use clear cache or no cache as this is not a simple HttpRequest instead I'm making API calls where I can't modify the header.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining this

```
App.PersonalizedViewModel.favorites.Clear();
DataContext = App.PersonalizedViewModel;
this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
```

into `constructor` i.e. `Profile` I would suggest remove this code from `Constructor` and add it into your `OnNavigatedTo`. so the data will load after `navigation`

Your OnNavigatedTo Method looks like follows

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    App.PersonalizedViewModel.favorites.Clear();
    DataContext = App.PersonalizedViewModel;
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);

}
```

Might be your problem will solve.

### Edit

Try this query

```
 var results = (from find in ParseObject.GetQuery("Favorite").WhereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username) select find);
```

Tried this:

```
var query = from favorite in ParseObject.GetQuery("Favorite")
                            where favorite.Get<string>("user") == ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username
                            select favorite;
                IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();
```

Comment: Done. Still remains the same. Actually the Parse query is not updating. I ran a debugging and found the parse query is returning Count=3 when Count=4. :(

Comment: In `results` you are getting only 3 records right ?

Comment: Yup dude. That's the problem.

Comment: I tried it. But Parse doesn't support Parse.ParseQuery() So, I modified and added the edit version. STill not working.

Comment: Can you try this without using `async` and `await`? Just try it once if possible

Comment: Can't dude. That's the SDK! :(

Comment: check what it returning `ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username`

Comment: This is returning correct result. The query is working first time properly after that it's not. I think problem is with data binding.

Comment: I don't see the issue yet.  However, please don't move setting the data context and hooking up the loaded event to OnNavigatedTo.  That is not the actual problem.  Loaded event will fire when it fires.  If you don't have it hooked, then you simply won't get the event.  Moving it to OnNavigatedTo won't be the "correct" solve even if it works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Problem.All u want to do here is generate a new instance of the Page.U can do this in two Ways.
One Way is by forcing a GUID along with Page Navigation URI that will create a New Instance of the Page and your Load Data() will work.

```
      NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/MainPage.xaml?item={0}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

The Second Way to implement that Part of your Page in a User Control .Like create a User Control for Load Data() and put it in constructor.It will generate a new Instance everytime you load the Page.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persists in the front end,you can try this.

1.have you mentioned the below attribute in your xaml page?

```
 <UserControl Loaded="MainPage_Loaded">
```

So that every time the page loads the data will get loaded on to the page.

2.The data must exist, if you have no problem in the code behind as it is a WPF application and not a web page.

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes required..

Remove the this.Loaded from OnNavigatedTo.  That may not be required.

Second move the LoadData to OnNavigatedTo method

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

   App.PersonalizedViewModel.favorites.Clear();
   DataContext = App.PersonalizedViewModel;
   // this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);

   if (!App.PersonalizedViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
   {
       App.PersonalizedViewModel.LoadData();
   }
}
```

For the purpose of debugging, you can remove the line `if (!App.PersonalizedViewModel.IsDataLoaded)` and try.